# Should one create a new git branch for each issue?

Tags: refactoring, bug

As developers, when we are assigned a task, we have two options:

Create one volatile branch for each issue:

1. Pull master;
2. make changes;
3. push changes to new remote branch;
4. wait for somebody to merge it to master.

or

Use one permanent branch per version:

1. Merge master to version branch;
2. make changes;
3. push changes to remote;
4. wait for somebody to merge version with master.

Which of these two options is preferable and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Use one permanent dev branch per user

Can it happen, that whoever manages your project comes in and decides that another feature is more important, or that you need to fix a bug first? Then one branch per developer is doomed to fail. Or you complete two features and suddenly the feature you completed first is cancelled?

You need one branch per feature. Because priorities change.

Comment: Plus, depending on how anal your team is about reviewing code and about gate keeping you may want to have any change approved before it is merged back. Then branching for every issue is the only way.

Comment: I would have thought review after changes is an absolute must. Of course the review would be rather quick since you only need to review added changes.

Answer (score 1):

The common strategy is this: You have a company wide development branch. Any change, you create a branch from development, make your changes, when everything is done you merge the latest version of the development branch into your code so a reviewer won’t have any merge problems, you push your branch for review, apply changes due to the review, until it is accepted, and then you merge. You can tag the merged development branch, and most places will remove the new branch once it is merged.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like technical discipline challenges more than management ones.

> Mo' branches, mo' problems!

- Keep the repository as simple as possible

  - more branches = greater complexity
  - Sharing reveals conflicts sooner
- Make small, incremental changes
- Commit often

  - No less than every day
  - Ideally many times daily
- Pull before any push

Comment: Branches do not make complexity, all they do it prevent it being hidden.

Comment: Each new branch adds a level of complexity with more [merges between branches](http://tinypic.com/r/sy5sf8/9).  What if two features need the same shared code that other features do not? (Baseless merge? Additional branch? Code duplication?!?!?) Frequent commits into a single branch reveals conflicts sooner, reduces the magnitude of conflicts, and promotes better technical practices.

Comment: Thank you - You have provide a perfect example of the complexity Merges expose that exists anyway but it hidden by refusing to use the feature branch model. If two feature need the same shared code you have three issues - the functionality the shared code provides is a separate deliverable. The features that use it are then added to that functionality.  Ignoring the complexity does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: The longer any branch exists, especially without merge, the more divergent the code bases and the higher the risk.

Comment: The branches are not the problem, multiple people working on the same code are.

Comment: I’d say the problem grows with the number of changes made. Obviously 20 people make more changes than one, but one person not merging for three months is as bad or worse.